# Group data separately if a condition breaks,Cnd:true assign grp 1; cnd false :assign group 2;cnd true: assign group 3

Tags: python, sql

```
#input 
|--IDs-|--Value-|
|--da1-|--100---|
|--da2-|---80---|
|--da3-|--200---|
|--da4-|--300---|
|--da5-|--100---|
|--da6-|--100---|
|--da7-|--500---|
|--da8-|---74---|

Assuming the data is sorted by date ASC, I need following results. if the data is not sorted. I need to sort it first and then apply the logic as mentioned.

# Desired output for condition Value> 100 

|--IDs-|--Value--|--Group--|
|--da1-|--100---|----1----|
|--da2-|---80---|----1----|
|--da3-|--200---|----2----|
|--da4-|--300---|----2----|
|--da5-|--100---|----3----|
|--da6-|--100---|----3----|
|--da7-|--500---|----4----|
|--da8-|---74---|----5----|
```

I tried using for loop and updating groups by comparing each data. This was not efficient performance wise. I was wondering if there are any easier and faster way to do this. I am trying to do this in python or SQL which ever is efficient. In the following code I am updating the pandas dataframe each time.

```
prev_cond = 'Cr'
group = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
        if data.iloc[i,1] > 100:
              cur_cond = 'Tr'
             if cur_cond == prev_cond:
                group = group 
             else:
                group = group+1
             data['Group'][i] = group
             prev_cond = cur_cond
        else:
            cur_cond = 'Fl'
            if cur_cond == prev_cond:
                group = group 
            else:
                group = group+1
            data['Group'][i] = group
            prev_cond = cur_cond
```

Comment: Please provide sample data *as a text table*.  And show what results you would wnat in SQL.

Comment: sample data and sample output is provided. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `lag()` and some conditional logic in a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_value > 100 and value > 100 then 0
                when prev_value <= 100 and value <= 100 then 0
                else 1
           end) over (order by id) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by id) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Not actually, I want to increase the group number every time the condition is switched regardless true or false. So that, I have separate groups for each sequence of true values or each sequence of false values. Based on those group column values, I will further analyze each set. For ex: I might want to filter out all the ids which have sum(value) less than 300 with in each sequence or group. The group value must be unique to each sequence through out the data. While doing so, it is very important for me to preserve the order by date status.

Comment: @PrakashJamarkattel . . . That is what this code does.  It produces exactly the results you specify.